# Ember.js navbar

Tags: ember.js

This works fine:

```
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='main-nav-collapse'>
  <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
   {{#link-to 'index' tagName='li' activeClass='active'}}
     {{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}
     {{/link-to}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

But when I add in another tab below, and restart the server nothing shows at all..

```
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='main-nav-collapse'>
  <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    {{#link-to 'index' tagName='li' activeClass='active'}}
     {{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}
     {{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'orders' tagName='li' activeClass='active'}}
     {{#link-to 'orders'}}Orders{{/link-to}}
     {{/link-to}}
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Orders is "orders.hbs" and is just a static html page.. and in my routers.js.coffee file is the following route:

```
Dashboard.Router.map ()->
      @resource('orders')
```

Comment: what does the console say ?

works fine here
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/movevayezi#/

Comment: How does that make sense to you... why are you nesting 2 link-to helpers that link to the same route? You also don't need to pass `activeClass` ember handles this for you.